# Is there a way to determine when an iOS upgrade was installed?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, upgrade, install

Is there any way within iOS, or via iTunes on a computer, to see the date when a particular iOS upgrade was installed on my device (iPhone/iPad)? Not the date the upgrade was released, but the date that it was actually installed.

Comment: Good question still valid on iOS 11.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have updated iOS through iTunes, you can look in your iTunes data folder, on a Windows machine that will be:

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates\`

Then check out the timestamp on the iPhone..._Restore.ipsw file. That will be the date you upgraded (or downloaded) our latest iOS update.

If you updated it directly on the device, I don't think it is possible to retrieve its date.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac managing your iPhone, go to the iPhone software updates directory:

```
cd /Users/`id -u -n`/Library/iTunes/iPhone\ Software\ Updates
```

There check for the modification times of the `iPhone*_Restore.ipsw` which are the downloaded images:

```
ls -lT iPhone*_Restore.ipsw
```